# Android: RecyclerView `getChildAt()` returns null even when the object is on the screen

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, nullpointerexception, recyclerview-layout

I have an Android activity that contains a RecyclerView, basically, I'm creating a music player app. In here, the previous song button is supposed to find the previous element of the RecyclerView and perform a click on it (this will play the song), to do so, when I use `recyclerView.getChildAt()`, it returns null, resulting in error.

Here is the code for the `onClickListener` of the 'previous' button...

```
prevSong_bottomSheet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // We start by checking if this is the first song or not!
            if (songIndex.getCurrentIndex() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Nothing to play before this", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // Now, this simply return as we don't want to execute any of the following code!
                return;
            }

            Log.d(DEBUG_MESSAGE, "Original song index: " + songIndex.getCurrentIndex());

            try {
                // First, as we know that we'll be playing the previous audio, we start by decrementing
                //  the value inside `SongIndex`.
                songIndex.prevSongPlayed();

                // As the value inside `SongIndex` has been decremented, we use the same here!
                View parentView = recyclerView.getChildAt(songIndex.getCurrentIndex());
                // Now we extract the action button associated with this particular view!
                Button tempButton = parentView.findViewById(R.id.music_actionButton);

                // Now that we've got the button, instead of calling `startSong()` directly, we'll
                //  perform a click on the button, this way if we decide to perform some other action (in the future)
                //  once the user clicks that button, the action would still be valid!
                tempButton.performClick();
                Log.d(DEBUG_MESSAGE, "Previous song played successfully!");
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                // Lastly, if any error occurred in the above code, in the first line itself, we
                //  have already decremented SongIndex in the first line itself, thus, we increment
                //  it here to balance it out!
                //songIndex.nextSongPlayed();
                Log.d(DEBUG_MESSAGE, e.getLocalizedMessage() + "\n\n\n\n\n\n");
                e.printStackTrace();

                Log.d(DEBUG_MESSAGE, "Final song index: " + songIndex.getCurrentIndex());

            }
        }
    });
```

While running the above code, it runs perfectly fine as long as the next element of the RecyclerView is on the screen, however begins to return null when the view is off-screen!

Yes, I know that RecyclerView will destroy the elements that are off screen (or not even create them). To work around this, I have tried to use `recyclerView.scrollToPosition()`, even after doing so, it returns null. I've tried to scroll up to the position of the previous element and even 2 or 3 positions above it, still `getChildAt()` returns null. Apart from this, I've also tried to block the main thread to wait for the RecyclerView to scroll up (using an infinite loop), even after this `getChildAt()` returns null.

How do I solve this?

P.S. `songIndex` is a class that is supposed to keep a tab on the position of the song that is currently playing. Here is the code for it (just in case):

```
private class SongIndex {
    /**
     * This class is used to keep a track as to which song is being played currently, the data member
     * created inside this class would be regularly updated using the functions defined below!
     * Thus, this class will be used at various instances inside the program to know about the
     * index of the song (inside the RecyclerView) which is being played currently!
     */

    private int currentSongIndex;

    public int getCurrentIndex() {
        return currentSongIndex;
    }

    public void setCurrentSongIndex(int currentSongIndex) {
        this.currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex;
    }

    public void nextSongPlayed() {
        currentSongIndex++;
    }

    public void prevSongPlayed() {
        currentSongIndex--;
    }
}
```

P.S.S Another thing I tried to solve this was that when I reached the top of the screen (there would be more elements above, but none of them would be on the screen, i.e. the RecyclerView probably would've destroyed them), after that, I manually scrolled up so that the currently playing song would be at the middle of the screen (now it has elements above it), even now, when I tried the previous button, I still somehow ended up inside the `catch` part :(

Comment: `"[...] and perform a click on it"` - no, this is not a way you should do - instead you should find a "previous" (whatever it is) song in your data model and call your "playing code" on it

Comment: If you want to get right item position, you should do this inside an adapter. `ViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()` should do this, but you must do it on a `ViewHolder`, so you can perform click on a specific item inside adapter, and return this back to the activity, e.g. using interface.

Comment: @pskink the button when clicked is also supposed to change it's background drawable, this part of changing the drawable isn't inside the 'playing code', it's present inside the OnClickListener for the particular button. Should I move this part to the playing method, what makes you say that this isn't the way I should do it (Not cheeky, just curious) ?

Answer (score 0):

As per the code you shared the currentSongIndex is not initialized. It will have some garbage value so your if condition (songIndex.getCurrentIndex() == 0) will be false first time and songIndex.getCurrentIndex() will return garbage hence recyclerView.getChildAt(songIndex.getCurrentIndex()); will be null

Comment: No, I've initialized SongIndex. The part that's causing the NullPointer is the `getChildAt()`. As for not including the part where I initialize `songIndex`, the entire code is well over 1000 lines, so I just added the specific part that was causing the error!

Comment: @PriyanshBhatt you **should not** call `getChildAt` at all - see the comment below your question

Comment: then i would suggest you to change your approach as mentioned by @pskink in first comment.